# Whats the difference between call require on start or end of code line?

Tags: php

I see some people calling require in the beginning of project, but sometime i see in the end of project.

Whats the difference?

Thanks

Comment: When the file is included / required.

Comment: `require` inserts the required file where `require` is used. The difference is where it’s going to be inserted and you should just use it wherever’s appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

`require` includes an external php file into the current file at the point from which `require` is called.

For example I have two files named **a.php** and **b.php**.

**a.php**

```
<?php echo "Hello!"; ?>
```

**b.php**

```
<?php
require 'a.php';
echo " World";
?>
```

When running **b.php** the result would be "Hello World".

If I were to revese it as seen in **c.php**

**c.php**

```
<?php
echo " World";
 require 'a.php';
?>
```

Running **c.php** would result in " WorldHello".

Short version, `require` is placed at whatever point in execution the code that is inside the included file is needed.

A common use for `require` is to include PHP files with common function definitions used across the entire site or database connection scripts which would need to be included at the top of the PHP file to use them.